# Does the below code lead to a dangling reference?

Tags: c++

```
int& getRef() {
    int* ptr = new int;
    *ptr = 42;
    return *ptr;
}
int main()
{
    int& ref = getRef();
    std::cout << ref;
}
```

Is `ref` here a dangling reference after the call to `getRef()`?

This is how I typically reason about dangling references:

- A reference is an alias to an object
- If the object is destroyed, then the reference becomes a dangling reference.

However, in this case, it's not clear to me which object is the reference an alias to? And without knowing what the object is, I can't figure out whether that object is destroyed or not :).

Similar to the above, how about this piece of code?

```
int& getRef(std::shared_ptr<int> sharedPtr) {
    return *sharedPtr;
}
int main()
{
    auto sharedIntPtr = std::make_shared<int>(42);
    int& ref = getRef(sharedIntPtr);
    std::cout << ref;
}
```

Comment: You allocate with `new`, you never destroy with `delete`, so the (nameless) `int` pointed to by `ptr` and then referred to by `ref` is not dangling. It's a memory leak, but not a dangling reference. In the second case the destructor isn't called until `sharedIntPtr` goes out of scope and also isn't dangling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reference is not exactly an alias, it is a different variable that points to the same address that you initialized it with during all its lifetime.

If you want to know if a object is being destroyed or not in some conditions, you can take advantage of destructors.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class myClass
{
private:
    int x;
public:
    myClass(int _x): x(_x) {}
    int getX() const {return x;}
    ~myClass(){std::cout << "Object distroyed! Value: " << x << std::endl;}
};

myClass& getRef() {
    myClass* ptr = new myClass(42);
    return *ptr;
}

int main()
{
    myClass& ref = getRef();
    std::cout << ref.getX() << std::endl;
}
```

Here we can see that the destructor never runs and therefore the object is not being destroyed. That is because you allocated it in the heap and it will not be destroyed unless you use `delete &ref;`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is ref here a dangling reference after the call to getRef()?

No. It references the object you created with `new` that has not been destroyed.

> it's not clear to me which object is the reference an alias to? And without knowing what the object is, I can't figure out whether that object is destroyed or not

It's not destroyed so your program leaks. To destroy the object, you could end your program with:

```
delete &ref;
```

In you your second example you are referencing the `int` managed by the two `shared_ptr`s and there will be no leaks since the last `shared_ptr` that goes out of scope destroys the `int`.

Comment: Thanks! In this case, what 'object' is this reference referring to? Is it referring to the 'unnamed' integer pointed to by ptr?

Comment: @You're welcome. In your top example `ref` is referencing the object that `ptr` was pointing at. The memory allocated by `ptr` itself is released at the end of the `getRef` - but not the object it pointed **at** - which is the object `ref` is referencing.